# Css not being found in deployed grails application

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I'm using the extjs plugin  and I have the following line in my gsp file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'ext/resources/css', file: 'xtheme-gray.css')}" />
```

when I run the app using grails run-app I can see that this CSS is being used. When I package it as a war and deploy it as an application, I'm seeing an 404 error saying "css is not found'

My version of grails is 2.1.1

Here is the generated HTML

```
<head>
  <title>Sentry Information Report Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sentry-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/static/ext/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/sentry-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/static/ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/sentry-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/static/ext/ext-all.js"></script>

    <meta name="layout" content="ext"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sentry-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/static/ext/resources/css/xtheme-gray.css" />


</head>
```

Comment: Can you post the html of prod? The folder ext exists in the generated war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your error here. What I did to solve:

Updated resources plugin in **BuildConfig.groovy**

```
runtime ":resources:1.2.RC2"
```

And in the resource method, defined to look into the plugin for the resource:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'ext/resources/css', file: 'xtheme-gray.css', plugin: 'extjs')}" />
```

Comment: Even though I see it in the war file, I'm Still seeing the error  16:16:04,811 ERROR [org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceMeta] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Resource not found: /plugins/extjs-3.4.0.0/static/ext/resources/css/xtheme-gray.css. BTW my container is JBOSS.

Comment: I tested in Tomcat 6. Can you test in one to see if the container is the problem? Also you can check the folder `plugins\extjs-3.4.0.0\ext\resources\css` in the exploded war.

Comment: I tried with the exploded war option and I do see the file. Here is some intresting thing. ext-all.css is being used which is in the same directory but not the xtheme-gray.css Here is the html <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sentry-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/plugins/extjs-3.4.0.0/static/ext/resources/css/xtheme-gray.css">

Comment: Here is how I got it to work     <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'static/ext/resources/css', file: 'xtheme-gray.css') }" />

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it to work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'static/ext/resources/css', file: 'xtheme-gray.css') }" />
```

I will test it on Tomcat also. I havee to download it

Comment: Interesting. What html this generates?